# Delete events after dynamically adding Delete button to events.the Delete button is not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I added Delete button to event in ListDay after deleting event using Delete button the Delete buttons are not visible in fullcalendar.

```
$('#cal2').fullCalendar({
  height: 'auto',
  defaultView: 'listDay',
  events:this.myClonedArray,
  defaultDate: this.startdate,
  viewRender: function(view) {
    $('.cal2 .fc-toolbar').css({
      'display': 'none',
    });
    $(".fc-list-table .fc-list-heading .fc-widget-header").attr('colspan', 4);
    $(".fc-list-table .fc-list-item").append('<td class="w3-center"><button class="fc-delete-item ">Delete</button></td>');
  },
  eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    var x = "" + event.id + "";
    localStorage.setItem("delete_id", x);
    $(".w3-center").on("click", function() {
      var result = confirm("Delete Event");
      if (result) {
        console.log(event);
        $('#cal2').fullCalendar('removeEvents', x);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Before:
[image]

After: 
[image]

Comment: A picture is useful to illustrate your problem, thanks. But...we cannot fix your issue using pictures. It's a bit like asking a surgeon to operate on a picture of the patient! Please show enough of your code so that we would be able to reproduce the same problem if we ran it. Thanks.

Comment: how did you add the button to the event?

Comment: in viewRender add this ->$(".fc-list-table .fc-list-heading .fc-widget-header").attr('colspan',4);
                $(".fc-list-table .fc-list-item").append('<td class="fc-delete-class"><button class="fc-delete-item ">Delete</button></td>');

Comment: We'll need a full code sample adding to the question, not just a tiny snippet in the comments. Enough code to actually be able to reproduce the problem. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson in this there are 2 calendars  1)month-calednar  2)listday-calendar.
when user click the date (the date is used in listday-calednar).this is the code of listday calednar     

https://docs.google.com/document/d/10w8K5qP4rNGX79d7EfwxTnkguBO7gF1QRtY2Q8FEGfc/edit

Comment: No, please add the relevant bits of code to your question here, thanks. Otherwise your question is at risk of being closed as "off-topic" by the moderators. External links can change or disappear over time, making the question useless to future readers. And besides, you really want to make it as easy as possible for us to help you. Don't make us click on a separate link read through lots of potentially irrelevant stuff to find the right section. We are volunteers, we do not have infinite time. Also please include a more detailed description of your problem if you can. Thanks.

Comment: eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                var x=""+event.id+"";
                localStorage.setItem("delete_id",x);
                $(".fc-delete-button").on("click", function() {
                  var result = confirm("Delete Event");
                if(result){
                  console.log(event);
                  
               
 $('#cal2').fullCalendar('removeEvents',localStorage.getItem("delete_id"));    
                  $('#cal2').fullCalendar('render');       
                }
                });
              },

Comment: No please add to the question itself, not the comments. Then you can include more info, and you can also format it properly to be readable. Use the "edit" button just under your question (near the little blue fullCalendar tag) to make changes. Thank you.

Comment: Here's a working demo using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/vf0pkjzh/ with some sample event data. It does not reproduce your problem. The delete buttons do not disappear. I suspect you have not shown us the code which is executed when the Delete button is pressed - I would guess that is where the problem is happening.

Comment: thanks @ADyson Please check this once http://jsfiddle.net/18ksmyhv/

Comment: Super @ADyson thanks for did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you've got here is that you are adding the delete buttons when the view is rendered.

However, rendering the view (i.e. the calendar grid) and rendering the events are separate processes. Your code only works (at startup) currently because you load a static set of events from an array. If you were using AJAX for the event source, then it would fail to add the buttons because the events would be rendered later than the view (i.e. the elements with those CSS classes wouldn't exist yet when you tried to select them with jQuery).

This leads onto why it fails after you delete an event: deletion of a single event causes *all* the events to be re-rendered (in case their position or size needs to change). However it does not cause the *view* to be re-rendered. Therefore the code which adds the delete buttons does not run.

The obvious solution to this would be to use the [eventAfterAllRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAfterAllRender) callback instead. This ensures the code runs every time after all the events have finished being added to the calendar.

However, this turns out not to be the final answer. Another niggling problem you had is that you have to click twice on the "Delete" button before it will work. This was because you didn't attach a "click" event to the button until the user had clicked at least once on an event.

The way to fix this is to use the [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) callback to add each button to its event individually *before* it has been added to the calendar, and then straight away attach the click event to it, so it's ready to be clicked on immediately when the event is displayed.

So actually the code to add the button is now in eventRender rather than eventAfterAllRender. All that's necessary to do before that is set the colspan on the list header...and that can be handled in viewRender quite happily, because it doesn't need re-drawing after an event is deleted.

Here's the completed code:

```
  $('#cal2').fullCalendar({
    height: 'auto',
    defaultView: 'listDay',
    events: this.myClonedArray,
    defaultDate: this.startdate,
    viewRender: function(view) {
      $('.cal2 .fc-toolbar').css({
        'display': 'none',
      });
      $(".fc-list-table .fc-list-heading .fc-widget-header").attr('colspan', 4);
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
      element.append('<td class="w3-center"><button class="fc-delete-item ">Delete</button></td>');
      element.find(".w3-center").on("click", function() {
        var result = confirm("Delete Event");
        if (result) {
          console.log(event);
          localStorage.setItem("delete_id", event.id);
          $('#cal2').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
        }
      });
    },
  });
```

And here's a runnable demo: http://jsfiddle.net/108sad4f/3/